# How to remove an element from a list by matching parts of its name?

Tags: r, list

I have a list like:

```
    foo<- list(c("foob.10.27808", "foob.11.31809","foob.12.35810","foob.13.39811", 
         "foob.14.43812", "foob.15.47813", "foob.16.51814", "foob.17.<NA>", 
         "foob.5.7803", "foob.6.11804", "foob.7.15805", "foob.8.19806", 
         "foob.9.23807")
```

Now I want to remove the object with the name `"foob.17.<NA>`. This should be no problem if I want to do it manually like `foo$foob.17.<NA><-NULL` or if I would exacly know what its name is, but first I don't want to do it manually (of course not ;)) and second, I don't know its name in every case. 
Those lists are created inside a function so the only part of its name I do know is `".<NA>"`.

Is there a way to find the name only by matching it with `".<NA>"` an remove it afterwards? Like it's done with environment elements with `rm(list=ls(pattern="foo"))`?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards, 
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `foo$"foob.17.<NA>" <- NULL` will not work because the list has no component with the name  `"ffoob.17.<NA>"` .  The list has only one component and that component contains a character vector.

`grep` can be used:

```
list(grep(".<NA>", foo[[1]], value = TRUE, invert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE))

## [[1]]
##  [1] "foob.10.27808" "foob.11.31809" "foob.12.35810" "foob.13.39811"
##  [5] "foob.14.43812" "foob.15.47813" "foob.16.51814" "foob.5.7803"  
##  [9] "foob.6.11804"  "foob.7.15805"  "foob.8.19806"  "foob.9.23807"
```

If you meant to write `foo2` where `foo2` is shown below then we can use `Filter`:

```
foo2 <- as.list(foo[[1]])
Filter(function(x) !grepl(".<NA", x, fixed = TRUE), foo2)
```

or if you meant you have a list whose names are the character vector `foo[[1]]` as shown below then:

```
foo3 <- setNames(as.list(seq_along(foo[[1]])), foo[[1]])
foo3[ grep(".<NA>", names(foo3), invert = TRUE, fixed = TRUE) ]
```

**Note:** `foo` in the question had unbalanced parentheses so here it is in reproducible form with that fixed:

```
foo<- list(c("foob.10.27808", "foob.11.31809","foob.12.35810","foob.13.39811", 
         "foob.14.43812", "foob.15.47813", "foob.16.51814", "foob.17.<NA>", 
         "foob.5.7803", "foob.6.11804", "foob.7.15805", "foob.8.19806", 
         "foob.9.23807"))
```